# Convert MySQL .sql file to MS Access Database

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

is there a way out to convert .sql to access database using php.
i have tried exporting the sql to csv format and then converting csv to access but only the data comes the column names are gone.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE (year = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['year']) . "') and ( branch= '" .
        mysql_real_escape_string(($_SESSION['branch'])). "') and ( sem= '" . mysql_real_escape_string(($_SESSION['sem'])). "') and (sec= '" .
        mysql_real_escape_string(($_SESSION['sec'])). "')"); 
print "<body background='bg.jpg'>"; 
Print "<br><br><BR><center><table border cellpadding=3><tr><th>idno</th><th>name</th><th>subject</th><th>Held Classes</th><th>Attended Classes</th></tr>";  
while($data=mysql_fetch_array( $sql ))   { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$data['idno']." </td><td>".$data['name'] . " <td>".$data['subject']." </td><td>".$data['heldcls'] . "<td>".$data['attendcls']." </td>"; 
} 
Print "</table><br><br><form action = excel.php method = POST><input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' Value = 'Export to excel'></form></center>";
```

Comment: When you say "convert .sql to access database" do you mean that you have a .sql file as produced by `mysqldump` (or similar) consisting of CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements and you want to get that information into an Access database?

Comment: i have a database which i have exported from phpmyadmin.. i want all the tables and data in same format in msaccess

Comment: Can the machine on which you are running Access communicate with the MySQL server holding the database that the .sql file came from?

Comment: can u tell me the connection string for ms-access and php.. i will outpur everything from ms sql and insert the records in access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("hostname", "dbuser", "dbpwd", "dbname");

$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection")
or die("Cannot start ADO");
$connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=/onlineadmission.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=*********;";
  $conn->open($connStr);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student");
$del="DELETE FROM student";
if ($conn->Execute($del) === false) {
         print 'error inserting: '.$conn->ErrorMsg().'<BR>';
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $var1=$row[0];
 $sql="INSERT INTO student
VALUES
('$var1')";
if ($conn->Execute($sql) === false) {

         print 'error inserting: '.$conn->ErrorMsg().'<BR>';
}
  }
echo "records inserted";
?>
```

the $con variable is used for the mysql connection... the $conn (notice a another 'n') is used for the adodb connection that is the connection used for msaccess...
Data source=/onlinead**.mdb.. this file is in c:/

the code first deletes all the records in the mdb file and then uploads whatever records present in phpmyadmin i.e. ur database...

Comment: Please add a few lines to explain your answer, thanks.